# c# background service launched as service cant retrieve json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, service

I am trying to run a background service as service.
It works fine if i run from the .exe  ....
i add it as service with `sc.exe create ".NET Joke Service" binpath="C:\Path\To\App.WindowsService.exe"`
on start i get error :
*Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<$>b__1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\MVCWat\WorkerService\Program.cs:line 21*

if i write the conn string directly in the options of program.cs without trying to retrieve it from json,  error moves on the next

**value im trying to retrieve from appsettings.json**
appsettings.json is

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDb": "server=localhost\\SQL2019;Trusted_Connection=True;database=myDb"

  },
  "paths": {

    "Ordrinipath": "D:\\aro\\Wat\\",
    "OrdriniLavpath": "D:\\aro\\Wat\\",
    "OrdriniClosedpath": "D:\\aro\\Wat\\",
    "OrdriniArchivepath": "D:\\aro\\Wat\\ARCH\\",

    "PICpath": "D:\\aro\\Wat\\"

  },
  "time": {
    "refreshRate" : 10000
  }
}
```

program.cs is :

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
         IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
        services.AddDbContext<MyConnContext>(
                            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddHostedService<WorkerOrAp>();
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerOLav>();
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerOrusi>();
        services.AddScoped<IDMSDo, DmsDo>();
        services.AddScoped<IXWat, XWatService>();
       
    })
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

AFTER ADDING TO PROGRAM

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

event errors :
application:
Login failed for user 'NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

system:
error:
The .wj service failed to start due to the following error:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
warning:
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{15698135-4EFAF-698A-B65C-44A5B7FAFFA44}
and APPID
{845A2E3D-11A3-CD3A-25AB-11AA2364FA2AC2FF}
to the user DESKTOP-OP9LL57K\USER SID (S-1-6-12-658921568-1238569127-4569258915-7812) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: Please post your appsettings.json and your program.cs

Comment: A service runs with a System Account that doesn't contain environmental variables so PATH is not defined.  Try starting server with RUN AS.

Comment: if i use logon  as "my user" i get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 services start with their current working directory set to a system directory, *not* where there process executable is.

It's common to do something like this at the beginning of `Main`:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Comment: indeed after this the service react like when i specified the path  for file location with "sc.exe create  --contentRoot" . i used :  User Id=sa;Password=Password123!; instead of trusted to avoid usr issues...i tryed switching as log on betwean loal system and my user. i get errors : added @ question end

Comment: @antikern: That's a completely different question. I recommend you post a new question that asks about the new problem.

Comment: i need to add either this line or when creating service specify the file location.             Also i found that in order to avoid modifying Local System access to SQL i  rather log on in the service as my user domain\localuser.   after this the service worked,  tho it doesn't keep active.    It does it job but fails to respond in a timely fashion so service doesn't keep on running and terminates. but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting all of the code regarding the issue.

I see two problems that could be the source:

1. right-click on `appsettings.json` and Copy to Output must read "Copy Always"
2. Check `apssetings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`, if you have a different build you must make sure the `AppDb` exists in the final execution in your build directory.
3. You are running the service, you must make sure that `binpath="C:\Path\To\` has `appsettings.json` and the AppDb exists in there.

I hope it helps
Cheers

Comment: well it runs fine as .exe and yes  sc.exe create ".NET Joke Service" binpath="C:\Path\To\App\WindowsService.exe"   all published files are in C:\Path\To\App\